# When to use Firebase cloud functions

Tags: node.js, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I have a Flutter app with Firestore backend. I set up a cloud function to use Stripe payment. But I am a bit confused about cloud functions - should I only be using it only when I need to react to a certain event (e.g. new user created) and/or performing complex database operations (writing multiple documents)? And for example, if I just need to read a single document, there is no need to create a cloud function right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is rather broad.  There are a LOT of reasons why one would choose to use a Cloud Function rather than direct data access, and a full discussion won't really fit here, but I'll boil it down to a simplification.

If you don't know if you need to use Cloud Functions, and you're able to get by safely without one, then you probably don't need it.  The moment you're not able to get by with direct access, then it's time to consider using a function.

Don't use Cloud Functions if you think you *might* need one.  Only use one if you *know* you need one, because direct client access is unsafe or inadequate.

Comment: So cloud functions are unnecessary for database reads? My main question is that some of my data is nested; for example, a `item` document has a reference to the item creator document, and the item creator document may have another reference to another document. It is fine to have the app handle these nested database reads correct?

Comment: It's unnecessary for reads, unless you're not able to craft a security rules that sufficiently constrains access to the client.  You have to decide.  If it works for you, then you don't have to change anything.  Firestore references are not automatically fetched.

Comment: for actually charge from a card we need to use cloud functions ? I am confused